# Trying to implement symmetric difference of two arrays but only removing duplicates

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java by implementing some algorithms independently. I am trying to implement a program that finds the symmetric difference of two arrays. (Symmetric difference of two sets is the set of elements that are in either of the two sets, but not in both.)

My approach was to first combine the two arrays. and sort this combined array. Then, after converting said array into an arraylist, I would loop through each item and compare each adjacent item. If two adjacent items were one of the same, they would both be removed.

Here is what I have done in my code (pardon the messiness of converting the arrays into arraylists and so on. It's obvious I'm still an amateur):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class symmetricDifference {
    public Object[] symdif(int[] ar1,int[] ar2){
        
        //merge the two arrays into an array called result
        int aLen = ar1.length;
        int bLen = ar2.length;
        int[] result = new int[aLen + bLen];
        System.arraycopy(ar1, 0, result, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(ar2, 0, result, aLen, bLen);

        //sort result
        Arrays.sort(result);

        //convert the array, result, into an arraylist called symdifar
        ArrayList<Integer> symdifar = new ArrayList<Integer>(result.length);
        for (int i : result) {
            symdifar.add(i);
        }
        
        //set i as 0 and n as the size of symdifar bar 1. check the adjacent items in symdifar. if items are the same, remove both and take 1 from n. do until i+1 is greater than n
        int i=0;
        int n = symdifar.size()-1;
        do {
            if (symdifar.get(i)==symdifar.get(i+1)){
                symdifar.remove(i);
                symdifar.remove(i+1);
                n=n-1;
            }
            i++;
        } while (i+1<n);

        //return the symdifar as an array called output
        Object[] output = symdifar.toArray();
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = {1,2,3};
        int[] array2 = {2,3,4};
    
        symmetricDifference ob = new symmetricDifference();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ob.symdif(array1,array2)));
    }
}
```

When I run the code, however, my output is [1,2,3,4]. I am expecting the output [1,4]. My method seems to only remove the duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you wrote: "When I run the code, however, my output is [1,2,3,4]. I am expecting the output [1,4]. My method seems to only remove the duplicates. What am I doing wrong?". Are you trying to say, that your method does *not* remove duplicates and *it must* remove duplicates?

Comment: I am trying to say that the method removes the duplicates as the merged list should be [1,2,2,3,3,4] at first but the output becomes [1,2,3,4], thus removing the duplicates. The output is supposed to be [1,4] as the other two elements, [2,3] appear in both lists. Sorry about the lack of clarity there.

Comment: Calling `symdifar.remove(i);` and directly after that `symdifar.remove(i+1);` smells like asking for problems. Consider that when you remove something from an `ArrayList` at position `i` all indexes > `i` will shift one index to the left. So calling `remove(i);` and then `remove(i+1);` will have the same result as calling `remove(i+2);` and then `remove(i);`

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `Set`s to implement the algorithm:

```
public Object[] symdif(int[] ar1,int[] ar2){
    Set<Integer> set1 = Arrays.stream(ar1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> set2 = Arrays.stream(ar2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> res = new HashSet<>();
    for(Integer x: set1){
        if(!set2.contains(x)){
            res.add(x);
        }
    }
    for(Integer x: set2){
        if(!set1.contains(x)){
            res.add(x);
        }
    }
    return res.toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've never encountered sets before so I will have to look into it before I give this question another stab with your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Two method are being provided and both have been tested using random numbers to populate the arrays.

Since you're passing `int` arrays
 you may as well return an `Integer` array instead of an `Object` array.

Since Java 8, a fairly standard way to convert arrays to
 collections is to stream them.  It works like this.

- First stream the array elements.
- Then box them (convert from a `primitive` to an `Object`.
  In this case an `int` to an `Integer`)
- Collect into a `collection` (in this case, a `set`)

```
int[] array = {...}; // some elements.
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Invoking the method

```
int[] array1 = {1,2,3,4};
int[] array2 = {3,4,5,6};
Integer[] result = symdif(array1, array2); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

The method, with comments

```
public static Integer[] symdif(int[] ar1, int[] ar2) {
    
    Set<Integer> set1 = Arrays.stream(ar1).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> set2 = Arrays.stream(ar2).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    // combine the two sets.
    Set<Integer> sym = new HashSet<>(set1);
    sym.addAll(set2);
    
    // get the intersection of the two sets.
    set1.retainAll(set2);
    
    // remove the intersection from the combined set.
    sym.removeAll(set1);
    
    // return the Integer array
    return sym.toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

The following shows how it might be done by simply iterating over the combined lists.  This presumes the arrays similar to sets in that they do not contain duplicates.  If they do, an alternate method using streams will be shown how create the `combinedSorted` array.

```
public static Integer[] symdif2(int[] ar1, int[] ar2) {
    int[] combinedSorted = Stream.of(ar1, ar2)
                .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sorted().toArray();

    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

- iterate thru all but the last element (to prevent an bad index exception).
- if adjacent elements are identical, skip them.
- otherwise, add the element to the list.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < combinedSorted.length-1; i++) {
        if (combinedSorted[i] != combinedSorted[i+1]) {
            list.add(combinedSorted[i]);
        } else {
            i++; // skip next one too
        }
    }
```

- now see if the last two elements were adjacent.  If not,
  add the last one to the list.

```
    int last = combinedSorted.length-1;
    if (combinedSorted[last] != combinedSorted[last-1]) {
        list.add(combinedSorted[last]);
    }
```

Convert to an array and return

```
    return list.toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

**Handling duplicates in the original arrays.**

The two arrays need to have duplicates removed **before** combining to ensure proper handling in the iteration process.  This can be done by concatinating streams of the arrays **after** the duplicates within each array have been removed.

```
int[] combinedSorted = IntStream
        .concat(Arrays.stream(ar1).distinct(),
                Arrays.stream(ar2).distinct())
        .sorted().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Double Call Strategy

By reusing your same ideas of `for's` and `ArrayLists`, we can reduce it to:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class A {

  public ArrayList<Integer> symdif(int[] ar1,int[] ar2){

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int a1: ar1){
      boolean found = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++ ){
        int a2 = ar2[i];
        if(a1 == a2){
          break;
        }
        if( i == ar2.length - 1){
          result.add( a1 );
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {1,2,3};
    int[] array2 = {2,3,4};
    A ob = new A();
    ArrayList<Integer> ar1Result = ob.symdif(array1, array2);
    ArrayList<Integer> ar2Result = ob.symdif(array2, array1);
    ar1Result.addAll(ar2Result);
    System.out.println(ar1Result);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 4]
```

Usually may become easier to understand with For's and ArrayList's before other solutions, your milleage may vary.